# Missing header file of Windows C++ Runtime while cross-compiling

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I'm not familiar with this cross-compilation thing, but I do have successfully built wxMSW from Linux before, with the cross-compiler provided by my distro. So, I guess it's okay to say that I have some basic knowledge about cross-compilation. The question is that when cross-compiling, it failed and told me that EventToken.h is missing. According to [Eventtoken.h header - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/eventtoken/), it obviously is one of the header files of Windows' C++ Runtime. **I don't have Windows, how and where can I install this header (and very likely some more other headers)?** Installing VC++ is obviously not an option, because I don't have Windows at this moment. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This answers the question - but I don't think it's a helpful answer - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/   Better option (in my opinion) is a VM running MS-Windows and MSVS Community Edition

Comment: This is not very practical.  File a bug with the project, use a stable release while they work it out.  Version 3.0.5 is the currently anointed stable version.

Comment: @RichardCritten Compared to GCC in Linux, both MinGW and TDM-GCC are running very very slow in Windows, and it goes even worse in VM. It's almost like a torture, but maybe it's my own problem because my PC isn't very good/expensive. It'd be the last resort though, to install Windows in VM. Anyway, thanks for the link. I'll install it if no other way is possible.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm trying to build wxMSW 3.1.4 from Linux, hoping to have Edge as the back-end for wxWebView. According to the manual https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/classwx_web_view.html, it's supposed to use Visual Studio to do the compilation. So, it's probably improper to file a bug report, because I'm not using Visual Studio. I was just thinking if cross-compilation works, it'd be awesome.